# Can we distribute computations to multiple machines without running an instance of the software in every machine?

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, distributed-computing

I am an architectural design student who works with 3D programs (like Blender, Rhino, etc.). I usually find that it takes a lot of time to compute heavy geometry. So, **I thought about if we could distribute the computations to a number of machines to get the job done quickly.**

Now the problem is, **I wanna distribute the computations without actually running an instance of the software I am using in every machine.** Because, I have read that a lot of distributed systems work that way, by running an instance of the software in every node that is doing the job. But, my question is, **can we run the 'master software' in only one machine, and just use the resources of many machines by running a 'supporting software' (that we write) on every machine to get the job done. So its like treating 'n' number of machines as 'one'.**

Is it possible...?

Comment: The short (and only) answer is: No, it's not possible. If there isn't some special program running on the other systems, there's nothing there to do any work (or to even listen for network communication about work).

Comment: I mean, lets assume I am rendering something in a software X. Can we write a program Y that can distribute the rendering work to multiple machines without having the software X in every machine. I am not saying nothing else should run on any other machines. I am asking, if we could run Y on every machine to distribute the work of X without having X on every machine.

Comment: I am definitely not an expert on this topic, but it seems to me as if you could have much more streamlined programs on the "worker" machines, and have more of a "master" program on the single machine.

Comment: Then yes, it's generally possible. If it's possible with your current software is a different issue though, and not really something that is on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of them in terms of machines, but in terms of resources. 
So instead of needing to run software on a machine, you need your software to be able to make use of a resource from a machine within your software's reach (say the network your "server" resides on) instead of the actual machine it's running on.

Unfortunately, most workstations do not expose their graphics card as a service. Unless you implement something like vGPUs (https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/technologies/virtual-gpu/) I don't see what you need happening.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am asking. I wanna use resouces of many macines. Can you suggest me some resources to get started. Is there any framework in python for distribution, or any good place to read about it?

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem is too complex for a single python module to fix IMO. You'd need a cloud of GPUs as well as the means to control each of them. Like nvidia does.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you mean by `supporting software`. In any case, the code that does the actual job has to reside in each node, for the work to be done.

You can, however, use the master-worker architecture where the master handles the job of distributing, collecting and integrating the result while each worker just sticks to pure number crunching. In this case, the softwares running on the master and the workers can be different as the master does more of a management work, but the workers still have the code that does the actual work.